# C++ The if statement is still true even when only one condition is met

Tags: c++, if-statement, operators, tic-tac-toe, tie

I am creating a tic tac toe program in c++ and am almost finished with it, the issue I'm having is when the game needs to end in a tie. I created an `if-statement` to check when specific combinations are selected and it finds it true even when only one condition is met.


Here is the code...

```
//takes the users selections and sees if all spots are filled in without a match.
if((b1== "O" || "X") && (b2 == "O" || "X") && (b3 == "O" || "X")){
        cout << "The game ended in a tie.";
      // Flip = 3 ends the game in a tie.
        flip = 3;
    }
```

ex... the game ends in a tie when i change `b1` to and `"O"` or an `"X"` even though `b2` and `b3` are still empty.

Comment: `(b1== "O" || "X")` -> `(b1 == "O" || b1 == "X")`, etc.

Comment: `if((b1== "O" || "X")` -- I'll make a bet that you won't see an `if` condition that looks like this in any of the C++ reading material you have.  So that should give you suspicion that this is wrong.  That's the danger when learning C++ -- if you go and "do your own thing" away from what you're learning, you wind up with valid, but wrong code being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition:

```
b1== "O" || "X"
```

evaluates as:

```
(b1=="O") || "X"
```

which is always true.  You probably want:

```
(b1=="O" || b1=="X")
```